# Entity Framework Regular Expression with Slashes but without Commas

Tags: .net, regex, entity-framework, validation

I have an Entity Framework model that I have put some validation on, in particular a regular expression to accept alpha-numeric, spaces and some punctuation.  However when trying to add a slash '/' as an acceptable character it seems to permit some additional unacceptable characters (in this case commas).

Expression 1:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[\w\s.()&'-]+", ErrorMessage = "Contains an illegal character")]
```

This works for all expected characters except the forward slash (i.e. it doesn't accept commas, but also doesn't accept slashes)

Expression 2:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[\w\s.()&'-/]+", ErrorMessage = "Contains an illegal character")]
```

This now accepts slashes (good) but also now accepts commas (not desired)

Expression 3:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[\w\s.()&'-\/]+", ErrorMessage = "Contains an illegal character")]
```

An attempt to escape the forward slash.  Same effect as experssion 2, accepts slashes and commas

Is this just some odd escaping or similar trick I need to do?  Some side-effect of .Net Regular Expressions?  I was definitely under the impression that "Expression 2" would accept slashes, but not commas, but that definitely doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '-' character must be the last character in a character class, if it isn't it defines a range of acceptable characters: [\w\s.()&'/-]+'

Comment: Genius!  Why won't this let me up vote you more than once? ... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the dash, `-`. The dash inside a character class signifies a *range*, *e.g.* `a-z` or `0-9`. (This is a range that is not lexicographic but ASCII-based. If you look at [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll see that a comma `,` (44) rests between the non-directional apostrophe `'` (39) and the forward slash `/` (47).) You need to put the `-` as the first or last character of your character class for it not to be interpreted as a range.